# Prevent frozen columns resize from extending out of the grid

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

In Grid component when I try to resize frozen column too much it goes out of the grid and there is no way I can resize it back to its initial position[This is an example from Vaadin sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVMug.gif).

Is there any way I can prevent frozen columns from extending out of the grid?

I tried to call setMaximumWidth() on frozen columns however this seems to not work on columns that are being resized.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the manual column resizing is not respecting the maximum width, so it's a bug in Grid.